# Earn value in scheduling

Tags: optimization, scheduling, cplex, constraint-programming, ibm-ilog-opl

I want to make a rescheduling, I have 2 modes with different earn value
mode 1 have a little earn value and long duration than mode 2.
If I want to make productivity * duration of activity i in mode m <= earn value in day 7 than choose mode 2 to reach the earn value at this day.
I already make the constraint, but i think it doesn't effect to my model. I confuse what's missing in this model. I need a suggestion.
**Earn value** is the project progress we'd got not in volume but in cost. for example total project value is $1000000. and every task have their value. for an example at day 7 we must got $450000 same as our planning form sum of many task that already done start from day 0-7

```
dvar interval Taskss [t in Tasks] in t.RelDate..t.DueDate   ; 
dvar interval mode[m in Modes] optional  size m.pt;
subject to {
 //Alternative mode of resource productivity in Cost's unit
  forall (t in Tasks, m in Modes) {
 // if(m.costprod *m.pt == 0 && 0 <= 559717712) presenceOf(mode[first(Modes)]);
  
    alternative(Taskss[t], all(m in Modes: m.taskId==t.id) mode[m]);
}
 forall (t in Tasks, m in Modes)
  (sum(t in Tasks)sum(m in Modes) m.costprod * m.pt <= 559717712 in 0..NbDays-14) != presenceOf(mode[first(Modes)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to model. What is the "earn value" ? Is it a constant parameter of the model ? Or a variable ? There also seems to be a temporal dimension attached to this notion of "earn value" as you mention "earn value in day 7". Does "earn value" evolves over time ? How ?

I think that you should formally define what you want to model. A small example would help too.

Comment: earn value is the project progress we'd got not in volume but in cost. for example total project value is $1000000. and every task have their value. for an example at day 7 we must got $450000 same as our planning form sum of many task that already done start from day 0-7